# ASP .Net MVC Download Error and Require to Recycle IIS Application Pool

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I currently maintain a nearly 3 years old ASP .Net MVC website, the application is running above **IIS (now in IIS 7)** and using **ASP .Net 4 Framework**. It used by client almost everyday and had a lot of upload-download file transaction. It also use **ELMAH** as Unhandled Exception Handling. The application running well until a few past month, there are a lot of report from user that they cannot do download the file, but without any error message, the download process just not doing anything while there is also no log in Browser Console. After doing several checking, all menu that have download function are using http response

```
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
        Response.Expires = -1;
        Response.Buffer = true;

        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", Convert.ToString(file_in_bytes.Length));

        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition"
                   , string.Format("{0};FileName=\"{1}\"", "attachment", fileName));
        Response.AddHeader("Set-Cookie", "fileDownload=true; path=/");

        Response.BinaryWrite(hasil);
        Response.End();
```

And nothing seems wrong (there are no Compile or Runtime Error in Development Server). We've also checked Elmah's log, but there no related error message appear in there. And This **problem is temporarily disappear** after our Server Management Team **do Recycling the Application Pool in IIS**.

This Web is also share Application Pool with another web, and when that error occurred, both application are affected, **only the download function that affected**, the other function like data retrieval from database, insert/edit/delete data is working fine.

I also checked the Web Server Event Viewer but there is nothing error in there. The very odd thing for us is that this error temporary disappear after we Recycling the Application Pool and after several days or weeks or months the error suddenly appear again.

Is there any log that we've missed to trace? or perhaps there is wrong with the Download code? **And why its temporarily fixed after Recycling Application Pool?**

**Another Note :** The data that need to be download by user is at **average 500kb to 2MB** in zip format contains several PDF files

**Update :** After few more hour investigating, I found that this web application using different method to Download, some are using the Http.Response like above code, and some are use FileContentResult as return value. But both using jquery.FileDownload in client-side. I also found this method in several Controller that has Download File method in this app,

```
private void CheckAndHandleFileResult(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) 
{
    var httpContext = filterContext.HttpContext;
    var response = httpContext.Response;

    if (filterContext.Result is FileContentResult)
    {
        //jquery.fileDownload uses this cookie to determine that 
        //a file download has completed successfully
        response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie(CookieName, "true") 
            { Path = CookiePath });
    }
    else
    {
        //ensure that the cookie is removed in case someone did 
        //a file download without using jquery.fileDownload
        if (httpContext.Request.Cookies[CookieName] != null)
        {
            response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie(CookieName, "true") 
                { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1), Path = CookiePath });
        }
    }
}
```

Actually I'm not really sure is that method related to this error or not, but it is called in a method that override **System.Web.MVC.Controller OnActionExecuted**, and it contain the line off adding Cookie for file download if using FileContentResult or delete Cookie if is not using FileContentResult and file Download Cookie is exists. It is Possible if Cookie is Accidentally not deleted / cleared after it created? And because the download method is frequently called by nearly 100 user everyday, it is possible that the Cookie is pile up and cause IIS Worker Process Crash?

I've also checked some references about Cookie and its relation to IIS Session State (My Apps using In-Proc State). Am I Close? Or did I miss something?

Comment: How are you loading the file into memory? and what version of MVC are you using?  The symptoms you are describing could be a memory leak.

Comment: The file that need to be download is created directly in web application, MVC that we use is MVC 4, if there is memory leak, where is the right place to monitor? because we already monitor from Task Manager, but there is no significant memory use, and we've also try to monitor IIS application pool virtual and physical memory, at this time, physical memory is around 700MB while virtual memory is around 1.5GB

Comment: Do you see any error code for the request in the browser or client side when you download?

Comment: What software are you using to create the PDF file, any chance of posting up a sample of the code or the product/package that you are using?

Comment: @Arathy No there is no error message nor any http status except 200. the jquery.Filedownload that i used is not throwing any error either.

Comment: @Adam im sorry i got confused first, there is 2 kind of file that can be downloaded, first its excel, directly created using NPOI, and second is PDF, but the PDF file is already created before through separate system and not related, my Web just stream the file using File IO stream and then download it. I will post some code snippet for file stream soon. Sorry

Comment: Just be aware of anything using the IDisposable interface.  This objects will need to be disposed of otherwise you can end up with memory leaks.  The FileContentResult actually manages that process for you, so I would focus attention to areas where you are passing byte data or streams into the Response directly.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why Response.Buffer is set to true? When buffering is enabled, the response is sent only after all processing is completed.  Can you disable it by setting to false and see if this works? This could be the reason for having to recycle the app pool. You can also check if you are facing these issues - [Help link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/925764/error-message-when-a-web-browser-sends-a-request-for-an-active-server-page-to-a-web-server-that-is-running-iis-6.0-response-buffer-limit-exceeded)